# Specifying the length of an integer in hook_schema

Tags: installation, database

Why does Drupal not allow you to specify the integer length with type `int` in `hook_schema`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [Data Types documentation](http://drupal.org/node/159605), I believe you can use `tiny, small, medium, big, normal`

Comment: My question was related to this issue.http://drupal.org/node/1477514